# Coding standards in React

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering how you structure your React code. I was writing a simple component, and while I wrote a lot of similar ones, this time I thought about two possibilities.

```
{this.state.scrollY > 200 ? 
    <div className={style.MobileMenu}>
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
    </div> :
    null
}
```

This renders a div if the value stored in the state for the scrollY property is more than 200. Fine, but if I have many more conditional renderings in my component I feel that this could lead to unreadable code. So my real question is if it might be better to delegate the render logic for that part of the UI to a stateless component like that:

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({scrollY}) => (
    {scrollY > 200 ? 
        <div className={style.MobileMenu}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBars} />
        </div> :
        null
    }
);
```

Then just import that component in its parent. Is it common knowledge, is it useful?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is totally fine. What I usually do is that I will offload this to a different function within my component itself (unless it needs to be reused across multiple components, in which case I would definitely go with what you suggested in your question) with a name prefixed with 'render'. Like this :

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    renderSomethingAwesome() {
        const {scrollY} = this.props;
        return {
            scrollY > 200 ? 
            <div className={style.MobileMenu}>
                ...
            </div> :
            null
        }
    }

    render () {
        return <div>
            {this.renderSomethingAwesome()}
        </div>
    }
}
```

In the above example I am using a class method, but you can also make it a static function and instead of accessing the props directly you can pass it from the render function itself